# Android - Actualizar TextView sin hilos

Tags: android, hilos, textview

quiero actualizar los datos mostrados en un TextView en unas variables que están siendo actualizadas cada 5 segundos... No puedo usar hilos por lo que imagino que va con timer/timertask pero no consigo solucionarlo...
En resumen, que quiero coger una string que está siendo actualizada por otra parte e imprimirla en un text view cada x segundos (yo solo consigo que se imprima la primera vez, me falta que este textview se actualice con la información de la variable que utiliza este) para así actualizar las coordenadas de localización.

Con este código saco la localización que quiero (Funciona perfecto):

```
//Metodos Ubicación

private void actualizarUbicacion(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        lng = location.getLongitude();
        speed = location.getSpeed();
        altitud = location.getAltitude();




    }
}

LocationListener locListener = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        actualizarUbicacion(location);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};

private void miUbicacion() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                PETICION_PERMISO_LOCALIZACION);
    } else {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        actualizarUbicacion(location);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER , 5000,0,locListener);


    }

}
```

Después de esto uso hilos para la hora y para otros métodos con una conexión a socket con xmpp.

Y para mostrar la información de esta ubicación, dentro del onCreate utilizo esto:

```
miUbicacion();

    TextView twLocalizacion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.twLocalizacion);
    String datos = ("Latitud= " + df.format(lat) + " Longitud= " + df.format(lng) + "\n Altura= " + altitud + " Velocidad= " + speed);


    twLocalizacion.setText(datos);
```

Intenté hacer algo con timer pero no me funcionó y en cuanto lo saco del onCreate la aplicación peta, he leído que tienes que hacer un timer que se ejecute en el hilo del UI pero no se como hacerlo muy bien... Aquí dejo el otro tema donde vi algo de información para hacer esto : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11730902/android-simple-time-counter

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com). Por favor, lee el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. 
Te invito a mirar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para más info. Un saludo.

Comment: Pudiste resolver este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer) infinito. Lo unico que tienes que cancelarlo al pausar tu Actividad. Por ejemplo:

```
private final int timeInMillis = 5000;
private CountDownTimer actualizador;
```

En tu `onCreate` o creas un metodo que se llame una vez haz lo siguiente:

```
actualizador = new CountDownTimer(timeInMillis, timeInMillis) {

      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { }

      public void onFinish() {
        // Aqui actualizas la data que quieras cada 5 segundos
        this.start(); // Esto hace que se repita cada 5 segundos.
      }
};
```

Debes sobreescribir el ciclo de vida de `onPause()` u `onResume()` para detener o resumir el timer de actualizar respectivamente.

Ejemplo:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
   super.onPause();
   if(this.actualizador != null)
      this.actualizador.cancel();
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   if(this.actualizador != null)
      this.actualizador.start()
}
```